# estimation of a parameter

Tags: parameter-estimation

The question is:
$x_i = \alpha + \omega_i, $ for $i = 1, \ldots, n.$

where $\alpha$ is a non-zero constant, but unknown, parameter to be estimated, and $\omega_i$ are uncorrelated, zero_mean, Gaussian random variable with known variance $\sigma_i^2$. Note that $\sigma_i^2$ and $\sigma_j^2$, for $i \neq j$, may be distinct. We wish to estimate $\alpha$ from a weighted sum of $x_i$, i.e.

$$\hat{\alpha} = \sum^n_{i=1}b_ix_i$$

Determine $b_i$, $i= 1, \ldots, n$, such that $\hat{\alpha}$ is unbiased and the variance of $\hat{\alpha}$ is as small as possible.

I have tried to use the unbiased condition and get that: $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i = 1$

I don't know how to use the variance of $\hat{\alpha}$ is as small as possible condition.

Comment: I posted an answer that you'll understand if you know about Lagrange multipliers, one of the standard second-year calculus topics.  For that answer you don't need to know about the Gauss-Markov theorem.  Another person posted an answer that you'll understand if you know the Gauss-Markov theorem, but for that you don't need Lagrange multipliers.  So maybe you'll find one of them useful and not the other, and which is which depends on your background.

Answer (score 2):

The weights should be proportional to the reciprocals of the variances:
$$
b_k = \frac{1/\sigma_k^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n 1/\sigma_i^2}.\tag1
$$
This can be shown with Lagrange multipliers.

The variance of $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i x_i$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2\sigma_i^2$.  The problem is to minimize that subject to the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i=1$.  The $i$th component of the gradient of the thing to be minimized is $2b_i\sigma_i^2$.  The vector whose components are those has to be a scalar multiple of the gradient of the function $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i$.  Notice that that happens with the weights in $(1)$.

Comment: how do you get the variance, can you show the process explicitly?

Comment: $\operatorname{var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i x_i\right)$ $=\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var}(b_i x_i)$ because of uncorrelatedness.  Then, $\operatorname{var}(b_i x_i) = b_i^2 \operatorname{var}(x_i) = b_i^2 \sigma_i^2$.

Comment: The sign of using Lagrange Multipliers is maximise and minimise problem with constrains, right? So next time I will try to use it when I encounter such situation. Thank you for your patient explain.

Answer (score 1):

For the unbiasedness, we have

$$
E\left(\hat{\alpha}\right)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_ix_i\right)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i(\alpha+\omega_i)\right)=\alpha\sum_{i=1}^nb_i + E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\omega_i\right)=\alpha\sum_{i=1}^nb_i
$$
and we get that $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i=1$ as you say.

Now, what follows is to simply make this homoscedastic so that we can use the Gauss-Markov theorem. Divide through by $\sigma_i$:

$$
\frac{x_i}{\sigma_i}=\frac{\alpha}{\sigma_i}+\frac{\omega_i}{\sigma_i}\Rightarrow x_i^*=\alpha\frac{1}{\sigma_i}+\omega_i^*
$$
where $\omega_i^*\sim N(0, 1)$ (stars indicate variance adjusted). This satisfies the usual OLS conditions, so by the Gauss-Markov theorem OLS is efficient and unbiased. The estimator then is:

$$
\hat{\alpha}=\arg\min_{a}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^*-a\frac{1}{\sigma_i})^2\Rightarrow-2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i^*-a\frac{1}{\sigma_i})}{\sigma_i}=0\\
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\sigma_i^2}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a}{\sigma^2_i}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\sigma^2_i}=a\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sigma^2_i}\\
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\sigma^2_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sigma^2_i}}=a
$$
so the weights are
$$
b_i=\frac{\frac{1}{\sigma^2_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sigma^2_i}}.
$$

Comment: You have a "$+$" where you need to multiply.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks (you mean for the expectation, right?). I'm a little confused though, why are our answers different?

Comment: Actually I hadn't noticed that they were different.  I look at yours more closely now.

Comment: The first dubious-looking thing I see is where you say $\alpha/\sigma_i = \alpha^*$ instead of $\alpha/\sigma_i = \alpha_i^*$.  Not all the $\alpha$s are equal. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: . . . and maybe that's the whole problem---I'm not sure yet.  At any rate, the fact that the variance of the estimator is minimized by making the weights proportional to the reciprocals of the variances---not the reciprocals of the standard deviations---is a fairly standard result.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That is, of course, a correct observation. The subsequent differentiation is probably as a result a bit off then. I'll take a closer look again later.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I fixed it now, it was what you pointed out that caused the error. Thanks for the help!